# Adding an icon to a textbox in mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently trying to add an icon to a text box in mvc5. I'm quite new to asp.net and I can't figure out how to do it. I would usually just use `<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>`.

Within the input area, however I have:

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m=> m.EmailAddress, new {@placeholder = "Email Address"})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap with ASP.Net MVC 5 (which is by default part of new MVC 5 application), then you can use bootstraps class to achieve that

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback"> 
   @Html.TextboxFor(m=> m.EmailAddress, new {@class="form-control" @placeholder = "Email Address"})
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

This code will display success icon with text box. Below is snapshot.
[image]

For more details on same look bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation).

Answer (score 1):

The Html helper you use there just generates an html input field, and binds it with your model's `EmailAddress` field. What you want to achieve has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC; it's just CSS. Your input field by default will have an `id` attribute of "EmailAddress". And you can just use some CSS like:

```
#EmailAddress{
    background: url(images/some-image.gif) no-repeat scroll 5px 5px;
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

just to give an example.

Alternatively, you can use the Html helper to give the input field some class like:

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m=> m.EmailAddress, new {@placeholder = "Email Address",
                 @class = "someClass"})
```

and style that class. 
Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
If you want to add a `font-awesome` icon instead of a bitmap picture inside the input field, you can also try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "someClass", 
    placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf007; Email Address"),
    style = "font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" })
```

Switch the font awesome code as desired. Alternatively, you can do this again with CSS:

```
.someClass::-webkit-input-placeholder::before { font-family: 
             fontAwesome; content:'\f007  '; color: #69f }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a css class or id to do that, and set your textbox with this class or id. For example:

**Css File**

```
.txtWithImage{
   background-image:url('images/usericon.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

**Asp.Net MVC Textbox**

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m=> m.EmailAddress, new {@class="txtWithImage" @placeholder = "Email Address"})
```